# Dynamic String array java

Tags: java, arrays, string, dynamic

I have a question.

You have the string "1;2;3;4;5" and you want to display them one by one. 
the result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I have programmed this so far.

```
package deel_3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class deel_3punt0 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            //bijschrijven van banlist
        //FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("File2", true);
        //PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        //lezen van de huidige lijst
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\JavaStuff\\testyeah.txt"));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Tim\\workspace\\deel_2\\n4d2 2.3.txt"));
        String IPF3_1 = null;

        while((IPF3_1 = br.readLine()) != null){
            //input splitten
            String arrIPF3_1 [] = IPF3_1.split(";");
            System.out.println(arrIPF3_1[1]);
            //het codewoord vinden
            String StrIPF3_1 = arrIPF3_1[1];
            //de lengte van het codewoord halen
            int mim = StrIPF3_1.length();
            System.out.println(mim);
            //bits losmaken
            String arrayinput311[]= StrIPF3_1.split("");
            System.out.println(arrayinput311[2]);
            //eerste whileloop goed
            String IPF3_1_2 = null;

            while((IPF3_1_2 = br2.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(IPF3_1_2);
                //input van banlist splitten
                String arrIPF3_1_2 [] = IPF3_1_2.split(";");
                //het woord voor de afstand vinden
                String StrIPF3_1_2 = arrIPF3_1_2[1];
                System.out.println(StrIPF3_1_2);
                //de lengte van het woord vinden
                int mimban = StrIPF3_1.length();
                System.out.println(mimban);
                //bits vinden
                String arrayinput312[] = StrIPF3_1_2.split("");
                System.out.println(arrayinput312[1]);


                int loop314 = 0;


                StringBuffer BFSTRING = new StringBuffer("");

                while(loop314<mim-1){


                //bits omzetten naar getallen voor de IF statement
                int getalIPF31 = Integer.parseInt(arrayinput312[loop314]);
                int getalIPF312 = Integer.parseInt(arrayinput311[loop314]);

                if(getalIPF31==getalIPF312){

                BFSTRING.append(0); 
                }

                else{
                    BFSTRING.append(1);
                }



                loop314 = loop314 +1;



                }
                double macht = 0;
                int loop315 = 0;
                double decimalewaarde = 0;
                String Bfstring = BFSTRING.toString();
                String Bfstring2 [] = Bfstring.split("");
                while(loop315<mim-1){
                    int bit_3=Integer.parseInt(Bfstring2[loop315]);

                    if(bit_3==1){
                    decimalewaarde = (decimalewaarde + Math.pow(2, macht));
                    }
                    else{

                    }

                    loop315 = loop315 +1;


                }

                System.out.println(decimalewaarde);
                FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("nieuwebanwoorden.txt", true);
                PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
                outputFile.println(decimalewaarde);
                outputFile.close();


            }







        }

        }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

}
```

I have a problem in the lines

```
int getalIPF31 = Integer.parseInt(arrayinput312[loop314]);
int getalIPF312 = Integer.parseInt(arrayinput311[loop314]);
```

I have used `System.out.println()` for checking where the error is.

Comment: Please don't use numbers in your variable names.

Comment: Please rename your variables with readable names.

Comment: Your code is a literal mess. What is `mim`? Just keep it simple first. Take the String `"1;2;3;4;5"`, split it into a `String[]`, iterate its elements and print them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way by using `replace()` method and `\n`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String number = "1;2;3;4;5";
        System.out.print(number.replace(";", "\n")); //Replacing the character ";" with the character "\n"

      }
```

This displays the string one by one.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```